# How to make search-engine friendly pages which display dynamic cross-domain api driven content?

Tags: ajax, seo

As part of a product we are deploying, clients need to access a remote API on our servers to access content and data.  Nonetheless, for some reasons and some clients, a solution where the entire page is on our servers is not desireable (reasons include: control over design, but mostly SEO, and them wanting this content to be available under "their domain")...  A script that accesses the API server-side is not desirable due to other issues.

My idea follows (and I will point out its flaws so others can please suggest alternatives):

1) Make a simple script to be hosted on the clients server which will obtain all traffic from a certain URI path (catch-all script, similar to any framework router).  so /MyApp/*.  This script would always return a single code, a "loader javascript and styling"...

2) Through javascript returned from the script above, extract the URL, and process the URI after the desired path /MyApp/[*] and send it to an external call with JSONP or CORS regular ajax, the return is then styled appropriately and displayed.

With this, a url such as /MyApp/abc and /MyApp/def would have the same html/js in the browser source, but the JS would load different data from the ajax call, therefore showing different content...

This would seem like a good solution, the only drawback is that from my understanding, google and other searchengines wouldnt ever be able to access the content from abc and def, they would only access the "loader javascript and styling" (obvious enough, they arent going to be running the JS)...

So this is better than #! in that it wouldnt screw with URLs, but would still be depending on JS, so not search engine friendly...

Due to server restrictions, I'd much rather have a simple "catchall" page, and have the API called from the client-side than have to impose minimum requirements such as curl, etc... plus I'd have access to the end-user ip address more easily this way (although I could make a more elaborate proxy - which would make installing it much harder on clients' servers)...

Is there a way of achieving this without conneting to the api from the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method of doing this IMO is to have an AJAX controller (assuming MVC design) to handle all remote requests. Have each action in your controller return JSON, and then you have easy access to the data with a serverside call.

Otherwise you are using the #! solution (which you don't like, and rightly so..), or using JSONP (a hassle as well).

Comment: Thks for the comment Zachary, an "Ajax Controller" you mean a server-side proxy, basically?  That would be slightly problematic because it will require supporting a whole bunch of different server setups, and our clients want to put the least on their servers... Ideally if I could find a way to do this somewhat elegantly using HTML/JS only it would be a dream come true, but i guess its not possible...

How would you suggest implementing this using JSONP?  (Dont forget I need the content fetched from JSONP to be spidered by search engines)?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Controller in MVC is just the part of your application that handles logic. If you aren't using MVC in your app, then it would just be a separate file that makes the AJAX request and returns whatever markup you need. Then in your page you can include your new file serverside. Otherwise with JSONP your best bet is using a library like jQuery, which streamlines the process.

Comment: The thing is that I dont have an "application" running on the clients' servers currently- they just link to my servers currently..  So MVC isnt really the issue.  I'd like to have something as small as possible, in a few different languages (to be able to support dif servers, wihtout being a headache), which would fetch the content...  I guess its never gonna work the way i'd like unless i make the request from this particular script (i.e. proxy through the clients server) even if i use jsonp, google wont index the jsonp-fetched content... oh well, thanks for helping me validate what i thought

Comment: Of course MVC isn't the issue.. it's just a method of organizing code :). The clients can still embed your returned data if using a REST API, serverside. If you intend on sticking with an API that returns JSON, it's up to them to include the data correctly for SEO. (Having one file to echo the content, and then including that file in the target page)